# Nginx. Как ограничить скорость отдачи на определенные папки?

Tags: nginx

Подскажите пожалуйста как ограничить скорость отдачи на определенные папки?

В папке /var/www есть три папки допустим folder1,folder2,folder3

Я хочу ограничить скорость отдачи с помощью limit_rate для папок folder1,folder2

Пробую так:

```
server {
    location /var/www/folder1{
        limit_rate 512k;
    }
    location /var/www/folder2{
        limit_rate 512k;
    }
}
```

Не работает. Как правильно сделать?

Comment: В документации к модулю [ngx_http_limit_req_module](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) написано как правильно это сделать.

Comment: location это не папка, а uri в запросе